# Calibrate 2 cameras that is facing each other? (openCV)

Tags: opencv, camera-calibration

Is it possible to calibrate 2 cameras that is facing each other?
If yes, how?

I have seen multiple camera calibration, and have tried the toolbox, each camera should have some overlapping area
but I haven't seen 2 cameras that is facing each other in the front (orthogonal) .

I am no expert on calibration but I am thinking about using a nicely printed  double-side chessboard. extract camera parameters like the usual way, and invert the x-y value.

Answers are appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In short: yes, it's possible. But you may experience some practical difficulties (depending on your setup).

Camera calibration can be decomposed into two different sets of parameters:

- **intrinsic calibration**. This is for everything related to the camera *per se*, such as the sensor size, pixel size, alignment error between the sensor and the optical axis...
- **extrinsic calibration**. This is to describe the position and orientation of the camera with respect to the world frame.

You can find an extended description of intrinsic parameters [here](http://www.cs.unc.edu/~marc/tutorial/node37.html) for example.
Since these parameters are *intrinsic*, then they do not depend on the particular position of the camera and can be calibrated in any setup.

Since *extrinsic* calibration deals with the camera setup with respect to the world, it is achieved by measuring the image projections of real world points.
If you can see real world points with known coordinates in any camera, then you can obviously calibrate this camera.

Having different cameras seeing the same scene piece only makes it easier to calibrate some stereo-related coordinate transform matrices.
In your case, you may have to perform a bit of extra math to find the position of a point from an image in the other image.